# Difference between \section{} and \section*{} in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I get a little confused about the difference between `\section{}` and `\section*{}` in Beamer. Could you please explain in detail with examples.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Brief Answer**

The brief answer is, 
`\section` inserts a new entry into the table of contents at
the appropriate tree-level and also inserts a new entry into the navigation bars.
But `\section*`
only adds an entry in the
navigation bars, *not* in the table of contents.

**Detailed Answer**

Now, let us go to the detailed answer, as you asked for. For this we consider this short file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\section{Section without Star}

\begin{itemize}
\item This will 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item insert a new entry into the table of contents,
  \item and will insert a new entry into the navigation bars.
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section*{Section with Star}

\begin{itemize}
\item This will 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {\itshape not} insert a new entry into the table of contents,
  \item but will insert a new entry into the navigation bars.
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

We are creating three slides (frames) here. The first one being the table of contents, the second with one normal section (*not* starred), the third one 
with a starred section.

**Output**

Now as you can see, in the following table of contents slide, name of the the normal section without a star, appears both at the navigation bar at left as well as in the table of contents. The section, created  with a *starred* command, though appears fine in the navigation bar, it does not appear in the table of contents.

[image]

You can compile the complete file using `pdflatex` and observe the effects. Please remember to compile at least three times.

**Additional Points**

Please remember that the difference between `\section` and `\section*` is only important if you create a table of contents and use a theme with navigation bar. Otherwise, you do not notice any difference. Perhaps that was the source of confusion in your case.

Also, please be advised that the case of `\section` and `\section*` in `beamer` is different from that in documents (`article` or `book` class).